# Magento 2 is not auto-updating the Sitemap XML but is set in Admin

Tags: xml, cron, magento2, sitemap

I am using Magento 2.2.2. I have set up XML in Catalog->Sitemap and in Marketing-> Generate XML. But when I opened the Sitemap XML, it is not updated at all. Please let me know if I'm missing something or where I can check the errors logs if there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error logs for Magento 2 are found under the `var/log` directory.

All system logs, cron logs, update logs, and other log data (like debugging and connections) are also found there.

Also, make sure that your cron jobs are up and running.

You can try running `bin php/magento cron:install` to make sure that the cron jobs are installed.

Then try running `bin php/magento cron:run` to execute the cron jobs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Checked in logs, there is not any error about the cron job and still not generating the sitemap file.

Comment: How about permissions? Have you checked the permissions for the directories?

Comment: Hmmmm. That's weird. Something must be blocking the generation of the XML file.

Comment: can I debug it somehow?

Comment: You can try monitoring the `system.log` files, or the `debug.log` files, and see if it mentions something regarding the sitemap file.